# Inequality to be disproved

Tags: trees, binary-trees

Suppose that a search for a key in a binary search tree ends up in a leaf. Consider three sets :
A,the keys to the left of the search path
B,the keys on the search path
C, the keys to the right of the search path.

Any 3 keys a,b,c belonging to A,B,C respectively must satisfy a<=b<=c.

How can I disapprove it? I am trying to generate a counter example, but could not find

Comment: I suggest you write a program to generate random trees, and try searching in them for a random element, and test whether each is a counterexample.  Have you tried that?

Comment: No no, thats a brute force method. Cant this be done via induction or something?

Comment: What's wrong with a brute force method to find a counterexample?  If you find one counterexample, you've disproven it.  It doesn't matter how you find the counterexample; the disproof is equally valid.  (Searching for counterexamples is a very valuable step: for one thing, sometimes you discover that you can't find any counterexample, which is a hint that maybe you should consider whether it's possible that the statement might be true.)  Anyway, this looks like a question where you should put in more effort on your own...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for 20 in

```
     5
    / \
   3   8
      / \
     6   11
```

$6 \in A$ and $5 \in B$ but 6>5

Comment: if we take the left child I, then B should include I. Why does B include the right subtree of x, C should include the right subtree of x, am I correct?

Comment: C will be incremented when left turn is taken, and A incremented when right turn taken. B is incremented whenever any turn is taken, since B holds the data of the path

Comment: oh I'm so sorry. I'll edit this completely

Comment: Is it all right now? Do you get it?

Comment: This answer is wrong. The statement is not true. The proof fails to compare the new elements in $A$ resp. $C$ with the previous elements in $B$.

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer to remove all of the incorrect statements.  Don't just put "The earlier answer was wrong.  Correct answer.  Original answer: ...wrong stuff...".  Just delete everything that is wrong, and keep only what is correct.  We have a revision history that you can always consult to see earlier versions, so there is no need to put "Edit: original version of answer:..."